# BufferedReader and BufferedWriter problem in JAVA

Tags: java

Estoy teniendo problemas con un programa, necesito que el programa procese 10 números escritos en un `txt` hacia abajo y me escriba si son correctos o no. El error es el siguiente:

> Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Stream closed
>   at java.io.BufferedWriter.ensureOpen(Unknown Source)
>   at java.io.BufferedWriter.write(Unknown Source)
>   at java.io.Writer.write(Unknown Source)
>   at NifCheck.main(NifCheck.java:18)

Aquí dejo todas las classes:

```
import java.io.*;

public class NifCheck {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    FileReader fr = new FileReader("C:\\Users\\Pablo\\Desktop\\NIF.txt");
    BufferedReader leer = new BufferedReader(fr);
    FileWriter fw = new 
    FileWriter("C:\\Users\\Pablo\\Desktop\\NIFCheck.txt");
    BufferedWriter escribir = new BufferedWriter(fw);
    GetNum numeronif = new GetNum();
    calc cogerletra = new calc();
    Check checkeo = new Check();
    for (int x = 1;x <=10;x++) {
        String leidostr = leer.readLine();
        int num = numeronif.num(leidostr);
        String letra = cogerletra.letra(num);
        System.out.println("Llego a escribir");
        escribir.write(leidostr + letra);
        escribir.newLine();
        escribir.close();
    }
}
}
public class GetNum {

int num(String x) {
    int largo;
    largo = x.length();
    String num = x.substring(0, (largo-1));
    int num2;
    num2 = Integer.parseInt(num);
    return num2;
}
}
public class calc {
String letra(int x) {
    String letras = "TRWAGMYFPDXBNJZSQVHLCKE";
    String a = letras.substring(x%23,x%23+1);
    return a;
}
}
public class Check {
public String Check(int num, String letra, String letrastr) {
    String codfinal = String.valueOf(num) + letra;
    if (codfinal.equals(letrastr)) return "      Correcto";
    else return "      Incorrecto";
}
}
```

Comment: Traduce tu pregunta estas en **SO en Español**

Comment: Como la pongo para que la lean ingleses?

Comment: entra aqui ahí le das en ask question https://stackoverflow.com/

Comment: Ya la traduje, no se como funciana esto muy bien

Comment: Primero que nada, cierra el *stream* `escribir` **fuera** del ciclo.

Comment: Vale arreglaste mi problema xd, perdon pero soy muy tonto aveces y no me di cuenta

Answer (score 0):

Sucede que dentro de la iteración en la primera lectura estas cerrando el stream con

```
escribir.close();
```

colocalo después del ciclo for.

Answer (score 0):

Los readers y writers no deberían cerrarse a mano, sino delegar su gestión a la máquina virtual usando `try-with-resources`

Resumiendo, en un try se pueden crear elementos que implementen Closeable (tus readers y writers lo hacen), y Java se ocupa de cerrarlos una vez se llega al final del bloque try.

Tu main debería ser así:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    try (FileReader fr = new FileReader("C:\\Users\\Pablo\\Desktop\\NIF.txt");BufferedReader leer = new BufferedReader(fr);
    FileWriter("C:\\Users\\Pablo\\Desktop\\NIFCheck.txt");BufferedWriter escribir = new BufferedWriter(fw)){
        GetNum numeronif = new GetNum();
        calc cogerletra = new calc();
        Check checkeo = new Check();
        for (int x = 1;x <=10;x++) {
            String leidostr = leer.readLine();
            int num = numeronif.num(leidostr);
            String letra = cogerletra.letra(num);
            System.out.println("Llego a escribir");
            escribir.write(leidostr + letra);
            escribir.newLine();
        }
    }
}
```